# How can I get that an atom colisionates to another atom? (in lammps)

Tags: lammps

[image]

With this code, I can get two atoms in different positions. Now, I want the blue atom to colisionate with the red atom (in repose). Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: +1, But have you tried to figure that out from reading the documentation of lammps? You need to define the interaction potential between the two atoms  and specify the simulation parameters, check the following parameters from lammps documentation: pair_style, pair_coeff, timestep, thermo, thermo_style.

Comment: I will try. If lose myself, I  will update the subject.

Comment: If you want to make them "collide", you will need to add an initial velocity for one of them.

Comment: @Camps I don't know how to do that :( (I'm totally new to this)